# Format data to be used in Highcharts series

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, highcharts

Hi I am trying to make a stacked bar chart using Highcharts, but the way the data has to be formatted to be consumed as a a series is tripping me up.

```
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [5]
    }, {
        name: 'ee',
        data: [2]
    }, {
        name: 'aa',
        data: [7]
    },{
        name: 'zz',
        data: [4]
    },{
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3]
    }]
```

That is how one of the examples is on their site for a stacked bar chart. I am using `$http.get()` to originally get data from a webservice, in JSON format like so :

```
{
  "id": 13,
  "name": "JohnSnow",
  "totalScore": 5.239947894580996,
  "models": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "Grey",
      "score": 75.5
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Black",
      "score": 1.2355425046127677
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Purple",
      "score": 24.0705126173457
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Teal",
      "score": 28.981312850901684
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Yellow",
      "score": 31.373482114014525
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Green",
      "score": 22.02040979235661
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Red",
      "score": 11.137161646416322
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "Blue",
      "score": 25.83014182677578
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "Orange",
      "score": 4.793888180490194
    }
  ]
}
```

My original approach was to go through the returned data from the `$http.get()` call and add a JSON object to an array that I would then set series equal to but that isn't working out too well. What are some other options, or are there easier ways to get it in the format. The data has to stay in that format on the webservice, so changing is out of the question. I have a plunker I am trying to get working [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HzK8tkQI0OOGGBDIKo5B?p=preview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

interesting question, I normally use either angular.forEach or a library called underscore to handle data processing in angularJS. Here is the forEach version.

```
data = $http.get(); // suppose you have the data
result = [];
angular.forEach(data.models, function(item) {
    // simple way is to take item as the original form
    result.push(item); 
    // or do your own way
    result.push({
        name: item.name,
        data: [item.score]
    });
});
```

Now the result variable is the one you want now.

Comment: Oh yea, this is a familiar solution. Sometimes I forget the easy way and just try and brute force it. Worked like a charm. Appreciate the help.